# opening svg with foreignobject with inkscape

Tags: svg, inkscape

I'm trying to get the foreignObject example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject working. What I do is:

- copy the source code
- save as a file e.g. /tmp/test.svg
- open with inkscape e.g. inkscape /tmp/test.svg

Then inkscape doesn't display the HTML text and on the command line the warning "WARNING: unknown type: svg:foreignObject" appears.

I have "Inkscape 1.1.2 (0a00cf5339, 2022-02-04)" on ubuntu.

Thanks!

Comment: Inkscape is open source so. 1. Download the source 2. implement foreignObject support (note that will be a multi year effort so maybe employ a team of programmers). 3 submit the patch back to the inkscape repository.

Comment: @Helge: vector editors like inkscape can't deal with `foreignObject` elements. Apart from browsers most applications will struggle to preview/render these hybrid HTML/SVG file content e.g. image viewers and also office apps.  If you need an reliable standalone svg – better avoid `foreignObject`.